# Ошибка сегментирования при работе с bsearch

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int comp (const void *x1, const void *x2);

int main(){
    char text[1000];
    char str[30];
    char *word;
    int  *p;
    char **arr = malloc(sizeof(char*));
    int N = 0;
    int M = 0;

    gets(text);
    gets(str);

    word = strtok(text," .,()\"");    
    while (word != NULL){
        N++;
        M = strlen(word);
        arr = (char **)realloc(arr,N*sizeof(char*));
        arr[N-1] = (char*)realloc(arr[N-1],M*sizeof(char));
        strcpy(arr[N-1], word);
        word = strtok(NULL," .,()\"");   
    }
        qsort(arr, N, sizeof(char*), comp);
        *p = (char*)bsearch(&str,arr,N,sizeof(char*),comp);
//for (int i = 0; i < N-1;i++) printf("%s\n", arr[i]);




     for(int i=0;i<N;i++)
    free(arr[i]);
  free(arr);  

   return 0;
}

int comp (const void *x1, const void *x2)
{
return strcmp(*(char**)x1, *(char**)x2);
}
```

Программа должная считать строку и слово, разбить ее на слова, отсортировать и сказать, есть ли введенное слово. Программа хорошо считывает и сортирует, но не может найти, выдает (Ошибка сегментирования (стек памяти сброшен на диск)). Что не так с программой? Скорее всего проблема в bsearch, но я не пойму где.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У меня главный вопрос: Зачем эти пляски с динамической памятью, если под `text` вы выделили массив из 1000 элементов, а значит токенов у вас больше 1000 точно не будет?

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int sort_cmp(const void* a, const void* b) { 
    return strcmp(*(char**) a, *(char**) b);
}

int search_cmp(const void* a, const void* b) { 
    return strcmp((char*) a, *(char**) b);
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    const char delimeter[] = " .,()\"";
    char text[256];
    char word[32];
    char* words[129];
    int n;

    gets(text);
    gets(word);

    char* token = strtok(text, delimeter);
    for(n = 0; token != NULL; n++) {
        words[n] = token;
        token = strtok(NULL, delimeter);
    }

    qsort(words, n, sizeof(char*), sort_cmp);

    char** result = bsearch(word, words, n, sizeof(char*), search_cmp);
    if(result != NULL)
        puts("Found");
    else
        puts("Not found");

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Я бы мог даже поспорить, что в массиве символов размером N  может разместиться максимум N/2 токенов (для четного N), а если N нечетно, то N/2 + 1

Answer (score 1):

- Что это за

  ```
  *p = bsearch(...
  ```

  Почему `*p`? И при чем здесь вообще некое `int  *p;`??? Не говоря уже о том, что `p` содержит мусор.
- ```
  arr = (char **)realloc(arr,N*sizeof(char*));
  arr[N-1] = (char*)realloc(arr[N-1],M*sizeof(char));
  ```

  Второй `realloc` получает на вход мусор в `arr[N-1]`. Почему вообще второй вызов - `realloc`, а не `malloc`?
- (Со вздохом:) Для строки длины `M` нужен массив размера `M+1`.
- Массив, в котором делается поиск, содержит *указатели* на строки. Ваша функция сравнения `comp` написана в расчете именно на это - она фактически принимает "указатели на указатели" в качестве параметров.

  Если вы хотите использовать именно эту функцию сравнения и в `bsearch` тоже, то в качестве ключа вам придется передавать именно *указатель на указатель* на строку. Ваше `&str` этому требованию не удовлетворяет. Нужно

  ```
  char *key = str;
  bsearch(&key, arr, N, sizeof(char*), comp);
  ```

  Либо так, либо писать свою отдельную "ассиметричную" функцию сравнения именно для `bsearch`.

P.S. И что за дикая вакханалия ненужных в С приведений типов?

Comment: Судя по тону Вашего ответа, прекрасный код в вопросе Вас немного очень удручает :D

Comment: @Kir_Antipov: Да, он вызывает у меня легкое бешенство слепой ярости :D